# What is the best effective way to collect data from a table using protractor?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

What is the best effective way to collect data from a table using protractor.

I collecting the data shown in the code below and it is taking 20-30 seconds for 10 rows.

The buildStr counter is for creating a object for every row, 8 is the number of columns.

```
    row = {};
    gridRows = [];

    element.all(by.css('#contenttableGrid div[role="gridcell"] div')).each(function(element){
        element.getText().then(function(text){
            row[headerName[buildStr]] = text;
            buildStr++;

            if(buildStr === 8){
                 buildStr = 0;
                 gridRows[rowCounter] = row;
                 rowCounter++;
                 row = {};
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to speed it up that I see is to extract all the data right on the page by injecting script on it. It could be done with the help of `browser.executeScript()` ([docs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript)). In your sample Protractor has to make a request to the browser any time you call `getText()`, nubmer of calls it makes = number of cells in your table. But using `browser.executeScript()` it will make one call and do all the stuff in the browser, which can be really fast. Then you can simply return this data back to a test spec and use it via Promises.

```
var headerName = {};
// I assume that this variable holds names for headers
// you can pass data from test spec to injected script as arguments (below)

// promise will be resolved with the value you return from `executeScript`
var promise = browser.executeScript(function (headerName) {

    // all the stuff inside this function happens on your page under test
    // it is not a Protractor environment

    var buildStr = 0;
    var rowCounter = 0;
    var row = {};
    var gridRows = [];

    var cells = document.querySelectorAll('#contenttableGrid div[role="gridcell"] div');
    for (var i = 0, l = cells.length; i < l; i++) {
        var text = cells[i].textContent;

        // `headerName` object is passed as an argument from test spec
        row[headerName[buildStr]] = text;
        buildStr++;

        if (buildStr === 8) {
            buildStr = 0;
            gridRows[rowCounter] = row;
            rowCounter++;
            row = {};
        }
    }

    // return all collected data back to test spec
    return gridRows;

}, headerName); // pass helper object from test spec to injectable function

promise.then(function (gridData) {

    console.log(gridData); // result of computations

});
```

Make sure to read [docs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript) for `browser.executeScript()` if you want to use it, because it has a lot of specific moments.